# Allow anyone permission in firesbase even in production

Tags: firebase

I have a web app that allows anyone who access the site to fill in some info and send it to my firebase. Right now the permissions are set to allow anyone to read and write and I keep getting emails from them that my database is insecure. Fact is I don't think I care if anyone access my database to write to it. Should I?

I was thinking how could I make it more secure, but still allow anyone who access my site to write to it and the only idea I came up with is to make a global user for the site and only allow him to write to it, but it would technically be the same thing as just logging in with the API key on the site wouldn't it?

Also only my back end would need to access it to read, there I shouldn't allow anyone, so how can I make a global user on my site maybe that's always logged in? Or is there another more secure way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: What is your **exact requirement** regarding access rights? Independently from how it should/would be implemented in Firebase. It may be totally valid to "allow anyone who access the site to fill in some info and send it to Firebase" if this is what you need/want. The emails you receive are just alert emails to help you identify potential breaches.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cloud Firestore, set the following security rules:

```
allow read, write;
```

The [Firebase documentation for Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files#understand_rules) explains that if no condition is specified, the rule evaluates to true.

If you are using Realtime Database, set the following security rules:

```
".read": true,
".write": true,
```

The documentation for Realtime Database can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

Comment: Yes. I am already doing that (ps thanks) but I keep getting emails that my database is unsecure.. Any taughts on that?